Unresolved reference 'load_model' with Keras 3.6 and TensorFlow 2.18
I’m encountering an error, Unresolved reference 'load_model', when trying to load a model in Keras. Here’s the code I’m using ( which i get from google teachable machine):
from keras.models import load_model  # TensorFlow is required for Keras to work
from PIL import Image, ImageOps  # Install pillow instead of PIL
import numpy as np

from keras.models import load_model  # TensorFlow is required for Keras to work
from PIL import Image, ImageOps  # Install pillow instead of PIL
import numpy as np

# Disable scientific notation for clarity
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

# Load the model
model = load_model("keras_Model.h5", compile=False)

# Load the labels
class_names = open("labels.txt", "r").readlines()

# Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
# The 'length' or number of images you can put into the array is
# determined by the first position in the shape tuple, in this case 1
data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

# Replace this with the path to your image
image = Image.open("<IMAGE_PATH>").convert("RGB")

# resizing the image to be at least 224x224 and then cropping from the center
size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)

# turn the image into a numpy array
image_array = np.asarray(image)

# Normalize the image
normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.5) - 1

# Load the image into the array
data[0] = normalized_image_array

# Predicts the model
prediction = model.predict(data)
index = np.argmax(prediction)
class_name = class_names[index]
confidence_score = prediction[0][index]

# Print prediction and confidence score
print("Class:", class_name[2:], end="")
print("Confidence Score:", confidence_score)

I’ve tried reinstalling both Keras and TensorFlow, but I still encounter this error. I’m wondering if this might be due to version compatibility issues, as I’m currently using:
Python: 3.12
TensorFlow: 2.18
Keras: 3.6
Pillow: Latest
What I’ve Tried:
Reinstalling TensorFlow and Keras with pip.
Changing the import to from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model, but still got the error.
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or knows how to solve it, I’d really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!
2024-11-01 18:54:49.115785: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:153] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-11-01 18:54:49.725096: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:153] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 234, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\convolutional\depthwise_conv2d.py", line 120, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\convolutional\base_depthwise_conv.py", line 106, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 285, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\TestModel.py", line 9, in <module>
    model = load_model("keras_Model.h5", compile=False)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 196, in load_model
    return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\legacy_h5_format.py", line 133, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = saving_utils.model_from_config(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
    return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 350, in from_config
    layer = saving_utils.model_from_config(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
    return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\sequential.py", line 350, in from_config
    layer = saving_utils.model_from_config(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
    return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\model.py", line 526, in from_config
    return functional_from_config(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 499, in functional_from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 479, in process_layer
    layer = saving_utils.model_from_config(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
    return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 504, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(cls_config)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC\.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\ops\operation.py", line 236, in from_config
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Error when deserializing class 'DepthwiseConv2D' using config={'name': 'expanded_conv_depthwise', 'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32', 'kernel_size': [3, 3], 'strides': [1, 1], 'padding': 'same', 'data_format': 'channels_last', 'dilation_rate': [1, 1], 'groups': 1, 'activation': 'linear', 'use_bias': False, 'bias_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}}, 'bias_regularizer': None, 'activity_regularizer': None, 'bias_constraint': None, 'depth_multiplier': 1, 'depthwise_initializer': {'class_name': 'VarianceScaling', 'config': {'scale': 1, 'mode': 'fan_avg', 'distribution': 'uniform', 'seed': None}}, 'depthwise_regularizer': None, 'depthwise_constraint': None}.

Exception encountered: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to DepthwiseConv2D: {'groups': 1}

Process finished with exit code 1


This is not a standard python error message, so what software exactly produced this message? Is it your IDE?

Can you show the complete error?

@Dr.Snoopy i dont is there any problems with my IDE or not but i thing there is something wrong with keras and tensorflow

@Frede
File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\convolutional\depthwise_conv2d.py", line 120, in init
super().init(
File "D:\BaiThucHanh\PythonFile\ABC.venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\convolutional\base_depthwise_conv.py", line 106, in init
super().init(
the error a lot more but i cant paste all them into this cmt

This does not answer my question. Its not about what you think, but what facts there are. You can paste full error messages in the question itself (edit it).

@Dr.Snoopy thanks this is the first time I use this website so I don't know anything and I added the error into my post

ok good, now the error message in the question title does not match the full error message in the question, seems the problem has nothing to do with load_model

It is not enough to install TensorFlow, you also have to import the module, or at least import the Keras module from the TensorFlow package (from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model).
However, TensorFlow is not compatible with the new version install of Python 3.12 since setuptools package is deprecated and TensorFlow will fail to load distutils. So you will also have to install setuptools and add an import of the module.

@Ze'evBen-Tsvi That has nothing to do with the problem, its just that the model was trained with a different keras version (from teachable machines) which is not compatible with the current keras version that the user is using.
